# Save locale language after restart the app using shared prefrences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have added language switching feature in my android studio application. This feature works well.

But when I restart the application, it doesn't start in the selected language.
It works according to the language of the phone. I could not find how to make the selected settings remembered.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
 Spinner spinner;
    Locale myLocale;
    String currentLanguage = "tr", currentLang;

    int flags[] = {R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.turkey, R.drawable.united, R.drawable.russia};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui_settings);

        currentLanguage = getIntent().getStringExtra(currentLang);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(getString(R.string.selectlang));
        list.add("Türkçe");
        list.add("English");
        list.add("Pусский");
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags, (ArrayList<String>) list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (position) {

                    case 1:
                        setLocale("tr");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setLocale("en");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setLocale("ru");
                        break;

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }
    public void setLocale(String localeName) {
        if (!localeName.equals(currentLanguage)) {
            myLocale = new Locale(localeName);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            refresh.putExtra(currentLang, localeName);
            startActivity(refresh);

        } else {  }
    }
```

CustomAdapter.java;

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.list = list;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.customspin, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(list.get(i));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following snippet

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Locale locale = new Locale("tr"); // get this value from shared pref
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = activity.getResources();
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        config.setLocale(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui_settings);

        currentLanguage = getIntent().getStringExtra(currentLang);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(getString(R.string.selectlang));
        list.add("Türkçe");
        list.add("English");
        list.add("Pусский");
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags, (ArrayList<String>) list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (position) {

                    case 1:
                        setLocale("tr");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setLocale("en");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setLocale("ru");
                        break;

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer.